# How to target an html element mobile menu with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I cannnot figure out how to target the buttons within my mobile menu to have it retract.
 I have it set to when clicked anywhere in the mobile menu (besides the buttons) and outside of the mobile menu to close the mobile menu but an not figure out how to include the buttons so that if they are clicked the mobile menu will also close. 
Any suggestions?

```
<nav class="fh5co-nav-style-1" role="navigation" data-offcanvass-position="fh5co-offcanvass-left">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 text-left fh5co-link-wrap">
                <ul data-offcanvass="yes" class="navList">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 fh5co-logo prime">
                <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-mobile-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="prime" style="width:100px;height:130px;" class="primeOne"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-right fh5co-link-wrap pull-right">
                <ul class="fh5co-special" data-offcanvass="yes">
                    <li><a href="#contact">Questions?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="call-to-action">Lets Talk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="call-to-action">English</a></li>
                    <li><a href="simplifiedChinese.html" class="call-to-action">简体</a></li>
                    <li><a href="traditionalChinese.html" class="call-to-action">繁體</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and the JS

```
// Click outside of offcanvass
var mobileMenuOutsideClick = function() {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#fh5co-offcanvass, .js-fh5co-mobile-toggle");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('html').removeClass('mobile-menu-expanded');
        $('.js-fh5co-mobile-toggle').removeClass('active');
    }
    });
};

//inside click
var mobileMenuInsideClick = function() {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $(".container, .js-fh5co-mobile-toggle, .fh5co-nav-style-1");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('html').removeClass('mobile-menu-expanded');
        $('.js-fh5co-mobile-toggle').removeClass('active');
    }
    });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile menu"?

Comment: I have the menu collapsing to the side when it is viewed on mobile. The menu opens when the expand button is clicked and I am trying to have it retract when any element in the expanded menu on mobile is clicked

Comment: i.e. you want to hide the menu again when an element of it has been clicked, has not it?

Comment: Yeah exactly, but for some reason that is not happening. When the mobile menu expands- and the area in there is clicked it will hide the menu again, but not when any of the menu items are clicked (for example clicking the "Team")

Comment: So if "about" or "team" is clicked it scrolls to the about id of the page but will not retract the mobile menu that is on the left side of the page on mobile, which is what i need it to do. The website is prime-opt.com